# Dar formato a un reporte de php para ser imprimible en formato pdf usando FDPF

Tags: php, mysql

Posee el siguiente reporte en php el cual quisiera darle el formato para ser imprimible en FPDF

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';
$proyecto=bd_rep1();
$alumno=bd_rep2();
$tutor=bd_rep3();
$alumnoi=bd_rep4();
$tutora=bd_rep5();
$asistema=bd_rep6();
$agas=bd_rep7();
$aeducacion=bd_rep8();
$aadministracion=bd_rep9();
$aagronoma=bd_rep10();
$aenfermeria=bd_rep11();
$proa=bd_rep12();
$prodesa=bd_rep13();
$proenpro=bd_rep14();
$prosis=bd_rep15();
$progas=bd_rep16();
$proedu=bd_rep17();
$proadm=bd_rep18();
$proagro=bd_rep19();
$proenf=bd_rep20();
$tutoraca=bd_rep21();
$tutorcomu=bd_rep22();
$tutormeto=bd_rep23();
$tutoresCarrera = bd_repxx();
?>

<h2>Reporte de Cantidades Generales</h2>
<table  class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
        <tr>
        <th><center>Proyectos</th>
        <th><center>Alumnos</th>
        <th><center>Tutores</th>
        <th><center>Alumnos Inscritos</th>
        <th><center>Tutores Asignados</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>    
<tr>
        <td><?=$proyecto?></td>    
        <td><?=$alumno?></td>   
        <td><?=$tutor?></td>   
        <td><?=$alumnoi?></td> 
        <td><?=$tutora?></td> 
</tr>    
</tbody>
</table>

<h2>Reporte de Proyectos</h2>

<table  class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
        <tr>
        <th><center>Aprobados</th>
        <th><center>Desaprobados</th>
        <th><center>En Proceso</th>
        <th><center>Proyectos de Ing.Sistemas</th>
        <th><center>Proyectos de Ing.Gas</th>
        <th><center>Proyectos de Educación</th>
        <th><center>Proyectos de Administración</th>
        <th><center>Proyectos de Ing.Agronoma</th>
        <th><center>Proyectos de Enfermeria</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>    
<tr>

        <td><?=$proa?></td>    
        <td><?=$prodesa?></td> 
        <td><?=$proenpro?></td> 
    <td><?= $prosis?></td> 
<td><?=$progas?></td> 
<td><?=$proedu?></td> 
<td><?=$proadm?></td> 
<td><?=$proagro?></td> 
<td><?=$proenf?></td> 

            </tr>    
</tbody>
</table>

<h2>Reporte de Alumnos</h2>

<table  class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
        <tr>
                <th><center>Alumnos en Ing.Sistemas</th>
        <th><center>Alumnos en Ing.Gas</th>
        <th><center>Alumnos en Educación</th>
        <th><center>Alumnos en Administración</th>
        <th><center>Alumnos en Ing.Agronoma</th>
        <th><center>Alumnos en Enfermeria</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>    
<tr>

                   <td><?=$asistema?></td> 
        <td><?=$agas?></td> 
        <td><?=$aeducacion?></td> 
        <td><?=$aadministracion?></td> 
        <td><?=$aagronoma?></td> 
        <td><?=$aenfermeria?></td> 
                  </tr>    
</tbody>
</table>

<h2>Reporte de Tutores</h2>

<table  class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
        <tr>
             <th><center>Tutores Academicos</th>
        <th><center>Tutores Comunitario</th>
        <th><center>Tutores Metodológico</th>
        <th><center>Tutores en Ing.Sistemas</th>
        <th><center>Tutores en Ing.Gas</th>
        <th><center>Tutores en Educación</th>
        <th><center>Tutores en Administración</th>
        <th><center>Tutores en Ing.Agronoma</th>
        <th><center>Tutores en Enfermería</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>    
<tr>

        <td><?=$tutoraca?></td> 
        <td><?=$tutorcomu?></td> 
        <td><?=$tutormeto?></td> 
<?php
    foreach ($tutoresCarrera as &$fila) {
        echo '<td>' . $fila['cant'] . '</td>';
    } 
?>
</tbody>  
</tbody>
</table>
```

es necesario pasar todos los datos a CELL, y volver a darle los valores a cada dato, como muestra este ejemplo: "http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script10.php"

Por otro lado que tan factible es la opcion de hacer la impresion de pantalla con javascript:

botón "imprimir":

```
    `<input name="btnImprimir" id="btnImprimir" type="button" class="button" value="Imprimir" onClick="imprime()">`
```

"Funcion imprimir":

```
    `function imprime(){
    //desaparece el boton
    document.getElementById("btnImprimir").style.display='none'
    //se imprime la pagina
    window.print()
    //reaparece el boton
    document.getElementById("btnImprimir").style.display='inline'
    }`
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema que tienes?

Comment: quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de que tal y como se ve mi lista en php se genere su pdf , sin tener que crear con $pdf todos los cell y darles formatos

Comment: Si quieres usar FPDF tienes que utilizar su sintaxis y eso pasa por usar los Cell para formatear las celdas

Comment: Una alternativa a FPDF es mPDF, mismo que es más fácil de utilizar, en [esta] (https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/98724/47499) pregunta explico su funcionamiento básico utilizando sólo HTML.

Answer (score 1):

ya casi lo resolvi utilizando el codigo que agregue, mas simple es sacar una foto y guardala en formato pdf, con el Window.print.

En javascripts creo el botón "imprimir":

```
`<input name="btnImprimir" id="btnImprimir" type="button" class="button" value="Imprimir" onClick="imprime()">`
```

y en un archivo Js la Funcion imprimir (imprimir.js)

```
function imprime(){
//desaparece el boton
document.getElementById("btnImprimir").style.display='none'
//se imprime la pagina
window.print()
//reaparece el boton
document.getElementById("btnImprimir").style.display='inline'
}
```

Seguido la incluyo al documento

```
<script src="imprimir.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

- Aunque la calidad de formato que obtiene no es muy bueno en cuanto son formularios que no caben completos en un hoja
- Segundo que no se auto exporta a menos que estes en un navegador como mozilla