# ¿Cómo empezar a crear pdf con la libreria mpdf?

Tags: php, mpdf

He tratado de poder crear archivos con esta librería y no he podido, agradecería su ayuda.

```
<?php

    require_once('mpdf/mpdf/vendor/autoload.php');

    $mpdf = new mPDF();



    $mpdf->WriteHTML('<p>Your first taste of creating PDF from HTML</p>');

    $mpdf->Output();

    exit;
```

Descargue la librería de aquí: [https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/releases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbJtl.png) y subí mis archivos directo a mi host.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Resolviste tu pregunta? ¿Alguna de estas respuestas te ayudaron o son la respuesta correcta a tu problema? Agradeceríamos que actualizaras el estado de esta pregunta y/o marcaras como correcta aquella pregunta que te ayudó. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que te falta declarar la funcion de agregar una nueva pagina

```
$mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8', 'A4-L');
$mpdf-> Addpage('L');
$mpdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', '16');
```

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar, ademas no he instalado eso de composer no se para que se usa, solo subí la carpeta de la librería mpdf a mi host.

Comment: descargate la libreria desde http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php, e incluyela en tu documento hasta el mdpf.php

Answer (score 1):

Primero que nada, debes descargar la librería de [aquí](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf) y alojarla en tu servidor, te recomiendo guardar todos los archivos en una carpeta llamada **mpdf**.

Una vez instalada puedes hacer una prueba de su funcionamiento con el siguiente código.

```
<?php
include_once("mpdf/mpdf.php");
$mpdf = new mPDF('R','A4', 11,'Arial');
$mpdf -> SetTitle('Ejemplo de generación de PDF');
$mpdf -> WriteHTML('<body>');
$mpdf -> WriteHTML('Aquí puedes poner todas las etiquetas HTML que mpdf te permite utilizar.');
$mpdf -> WriteHTML('</body>');
$mpdf -> Output('NombreDeTuArchivo.pdf', 'I');
exit;
?>
```

Te explico a grandes rasgos, incluyes la librería a través de su archivo principal con el `include_once`, creas un nuevo PDF con la función `new mPDF` ahí puedes asignar el tipo de papel a utilizar y la fuente, la función `SetTitle();` te permite cambiar el titulo del documento que se ve en el navegador, todo lo demás es simple HTML, la última función `Output();` te permite asignar el nombre por defecto con el cual el usuario podrá guardar el archivo si así lo desea.
Como eres nuevo en la librería, te recomiendo utilizar sólo etiquetas HTML para darle formato a tu pdf, mismas que puedes agregar en la función `WriteHTML();`.

Si está instalada correctamente, el resultado será el siguiente:
[image: Ejemplo de generación de PDF.]

Para hacer un diseño más elaborado puedes utilizar tablas dentro de las funciones `WriteHTML();`, ya sabes, con las etiquetas `<table>` y todo eso.
Te muestro un ejemplo de como puedes realizar un diseño limpio a través de etiquetas HTML y tablas.

[image: Diseño que puedes realizar a partir de tablas, texto e imágenes.]

Comment: Oye a mi me sale con una hoja en blanco y hay si la informacion como lo soluciono?

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que llevas? Osea ¿Ya te genera el PDF? Crea una pregunta si gustas y sube tu código para ayudarte :)

Comment: Ya lo soluciones muchas gracias solo era sacarlo de las etiquetas div y body. Sabes algo de python?

Comment: Se sólo algo muy básico, sólo lo que vimos en el instituto

Answer (score 0):

Hack Trick
Checa tu version de MPDF si es compatible con la version de PHP que estas usando una vez que veas compruebes lo mencionado, sugiero ejecutar primero en Windows ya que asi sabras si funciona o no, una ves comprobadad la funcionalidad con un ejemplo basico alojalo en el servidor, ahora viene la parte mas importante que es darle permisos para que se ejecute ya que se comporta como un archivo script que genera otros archivos por lo cual debes de dar permisos en tu LinuxServer en WOS no se necesita ya que por defecto da full permission, lo siguiente seria ver que te sale mas conveniente de las siguientes opciones

> chmod
> chown -R apache:apache tmp
> chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t tmp/